# JSON element pushing into array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am looking to access a HTML element's data (a JSON record) and push it into an array in JavaScript.

The HTML is:

```
<td class="card-holder" data-card="{"id":0,"type":"Wildcard","image":"wildcard.png","strength":0,"type_image":"wildcard.png","region_owned_adder":0}">
      <img id="card-image-0" src="/img/wildcard.png" class="card-exchange">
      <input class="cards-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="card-0" name="cards_to_exchange[]" value="id=" 0""="">
      <label for="cards_to_exchange"></label>
</td>
```

I have a number of these on my page. I read each in a loop and select some to push into an array like this:

```
var cards = [];
$('.card-exchange').each(function() {
    if ($(this).find('input[name="cards_to_exchange[]"]').is(':checked')) {
        var parseCard = JSON.parse(thisElement.data('card'));
        cards.push(parseCard);
    }
});
```

But this is showing me `[]` after the loop:

```
console.log(cards);
```

This shows the data OK:

```
console.log(thisElement.data('card'));
```

How do I read the string and push it into array as object? Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).find('input[name="cards_to_exchange[]"]').is(':checked')` is probably failing

Comment: Variant #1: `'input[type=checkbox]'`, variant #2:`'input[name^="cards_to_exchange"]'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `.find()` on an `<img>`, which has no descendants.

Use `.next()` instead to get its `<input>` sibling.

---

Also, you can use `.filter()` and then `.map()` to clean it up a little.

```
var cards = $('.card-exchange').filter(function() {
    return $(this).next().is(':checked');
}).map(function() {
    return JSON.parse(thisElement.data('card'));
}).toArray();
```

Though I'm not sure what `thisElement` is referring to.

---

You could even shorten it a little more.

```
var cards = $('.card-exchange + input:checked')
  .prev()
  .map(function() {
     return JSON.parse(thisElement.data('card'));
  });
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I had to get rid of the `JSON.parse` as this was causing it to error. Now all good.